# ExpressJS synchronous HTTP request processing

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have a Node ExpressJS application and I want to process incoming HTTP requests in a synchronous manner, because each http request calls the Gmail API which in turn has a limit of 15 concurrent connections for an account.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  callGmailAPI();
});
```

My ExpressJS application is reverse proxied through a Nginx web server.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await callGmailAPI();
  res.send('Completed normally.');
});
```

Comment: This won't work because `router.get` expects a callback not a promise

Comment: @slebetman The edited didn't work. Is there a better method of implementing this type of scenarios? May be expressJS is not a good deal. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you have a series of things you want to do in a synchronous manner, may I suggest `async.series()`? https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series

```
const async = require('async')
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    async.series([
        function (callback) {
            // Make Sure you call the callback here after you do your work
            callGmailAPI()
        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send('All Done')
        }
    }
})
```